# Packet tracer overlapping error

Tags: ipv4

[image]

I'm very new to packet tracer (day 3) I seem to get an overlapping error message, on 0/0/0 - 192.168.0.2/24, I couldn't assign 0.3 to interface 0/0/1 (overlapping) so I assigned 0.3 to PC0 and tried 0.4 on E0/0/1 and still get an overlapping message... even with 0.250 it say's overlapping, have I missed something?

Edit - [image]

Right, that's what I thought, I was able to get PC0 (192.168.0.0) to communicate to PC2 (192.168.2.0) but I can't get PC0 to communicate with PC1 (192.168.1.0) on the same router, my thinking is that PC0 and PC1 being 0.1 and 1.1 is the problem, I don't see how the image 'supernets in action' can actually be recreated since I would have to edit the IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

A router routes *between* subnets, so each interface needs to be part of a different subnet.

192.168.0.2/24 and 192.168.0.3/24 are on the very same subnet. You need to use some other subnet than 192.168.0.0/24.